# How to save resources on android when loading several bitmaps from assets that are needed in various activities

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, assets, android-bitmap

Sorry for the long title just wanted to be specific So I have several activities that once started should have all bitmaps in assets initialized, the code that follows works but there most be better solutions please all help will be appreciated.

Class that initializes bitmaps:

```
public class Images {
private String[]eyes=new String[]{
        "images/character/face/eyes/blue.png"
};
public LinkedList<Bitmap> eyesBM=new LinkedList<Bitmap>();
private int eyesIndex = 0;

private String[]faceandhands=new String[]{
        "images/character/face/faceandhands/white.png",
        "images/character/face/faceandhands/black.png"
};
public LinkedList<Bitmap> faceandhandsBM=new LinkedList<Bitmap>();
private int faceandhandsIndex = 0;
private String[]facialhair=new String[]{
        "images/character/face/facialhair/black.png"
};

public LinkedList<Bitmap> facialhairBM=new LinkedList<Bitmap>();
private String[]hair=new String[]{
        "images/character/face/hair/grey.png"
};
public LinkedList<Bitmap> hairBM=new LinkedList<Bitmap>();
private String[]tattoes=new String[]{
        "images/character/face/tattoes/test.png"
};
public LinkedList<Bitmap> tattoesBM=new LinkedList<Bitmap>();
private String[]legs=new String[]{
        "images/character/legs/brown.png"
};
private LinkedList<Bitmap> legsBM=new LinkedList<Bitmap>();
private String[]shirt=new String[]{
        "images/character/shirt/purple.png"
};
public LinkedList<Bitmap> shirtBM=new LinkedList<Bitmap>();
private String[]shoes=new String[]{
        "images/character/shoes/red.png"
};
public LinkedList<Bitmap> shoesBM=new LinkedList<Bitmap>();
private String[]background=new String[]{
        "images/character/background/normal.png"
};
public LinkedList<Bitmap> backgroundBM=new LinkedList<Bitmap>();



public Images(Context c) {
    loadBitmaps(c,eyes,"eyes");
    loadBitmaps(c,faceandhands,"faceandhands");
    loadBitmaps(c,facialhair,"facialhair");
    loadBitmaps(c,hair,"hair");
    loadBitmaps(c,tattoes,"tattoes");
    loadBitmaps(c,legs,"legs");
    loadBitmaps(c,shirt,"shirt");
    loadBitmaps(c,shoes,"shoes");
    loadBitmaps(c,background,"background");
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context context, String filePath) {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream istr;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(filePath);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Fudeu geral !");
    }

    return bitmap;
}
public void loadBitmaps(Context c,String[] src,String dest){
    Bitmap bit=null;
    for (int i = 0;i<src.length;i++){
        bit= getBitmapFromAsset(c,src[i]);
        switch (dest){
            case "eyes":
                eyesBM.add(bit);
                break;
            case "faceandhands":
                faceandhandsBM.add(bit);
                break;
            case "facialhair":
                facialhairBM.add(bit);
            break;
            case "hair":
                hairBM.add(bit);
            break;
            case "tattoes":
                tattoesBM.add(bit);
            break;
            case "legs":
                legsBM.add(bit);
            break;
            case "shirt":
                shirtBM.add(bit);
            break;
            case "shoes":
                shoesBM.add(bit);
            break;
            case "background":
                backgroundBM.add(bit);
            break;
        }
        //dest.add(bit);
        //dest.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, src[i]));
        }
}
public Bitmap getBitmap(String name){
    switch (name){
        case "eyes":
            eyesIndex=eyesIndex>=eyesBM.size()?0:eyesIndex;
            Bitmap aux =eyesBM.get(eyesIndex);
            eyesIndex++;
            return aux;
        case "faceandhands":
            faceandhandsIndex=faceandhandsIndex>=faceandhandsBM.size()?0:faceandhandsIndex;
            Bitmap aux1=faceandhandsBM.get(faceandhandsIndex);
            faceandhandsIndex++;
            return aux1;
            //return faceandhandsBM.get(0);
        case "facialhair":
            return facialhairBM.get(0);
        case "hair":
            return hairBM.get(0);
        case "tattoes":
            return tattoesBM.get(0);
        case "legs":
            return legsBM.get(0);
        case "shirt":
            return shirtBM.get(0);
        case "shoes":
            return shoesBM.get(0);
        case "background":
            return backgroundBM.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}}
```

´
Code from main activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_character);
    final EditText eT=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.characterName);
    v = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.characterDisplay);
    img = new Images(this);
    LD=null;
    DD= new Drawable[]{
            new BitmapDrawable(img.getBitmap("legs")),
            new BitmapDrawable(img.getBitmap("faceandhands")),
            new BitmapDrawable(img.getBitmap("shirt")),
            new BitmapDrawable(img.getBitmap("eyes")),
            new BitmapDrawable(img.getBitmap("facialhair")),
            new BitmapDrawable(img.getBitmap("hair")),
            new BitmapDrawable(img.getBitmap("shoes")),
            new BitmapDrawable(img.getBitmap("tattoes"))
    };
    LD=new LayerDrawable(DD);
    v.setImageDrawable(LD);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSkin)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DD[1]=new BitmapDrawable(img.getBitmap("faceandhands"));
            LD=new LayerDrawable(DD);
            update(LD);
            //saveCaracter(eT.getText().toString());
            //loadGame(eT.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

Update method:

```
private void update(LayerDrawable ld) {
    v.setImageDrawable(ld);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I know of is to use the Picasso library. It cuts down on coding by a ton. http://square.github.io/picasso/